# Azure deployment issue

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, azure, angular-fullstack

When I am deploying my spring boot application as a war file in azure and try to open it in the browser I am getting **The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process** this message and my application is not working on the browser. Help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the azure web app is not responding.
You can try the below workarounds as suggested by @Aidan Casey [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35132000/15969858):

- Auto-healing feature is used to restart the azure web app frequently so that our application will be running without making it to become idle.

> You can configure the server to restart on a periodic basis. This won't fix the underlying root cause but it may be enough to keep your app running. Check out this github gist for how to configure it in the `web.config` file

Also refer this gitub [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/736272/error-the-specified-cgi-application-encountered-an.html) for similar kind of error to troubleshoot.