# The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process when running on Azure Functions ASP

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I meet a problems when deploy my code to Azure Funtions using App Service Plan. My function is long running (about 4 minutes, for business logic) and when I call it by Post man, it response 502.

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process.

In this time my function is still running, I monitor on the portal of Function Apps and it return a success response after 4 minutes, but I meet error and can not receive the response when call from client.

[Response Message & Status Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM7Zc.png)
[Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Y5X.png)

I read below link and see that may be the limitation is from Azure App Service Plan, but how to config ASP to solve this error ?

Some information:
 - Azure Functions V2.
 - App Service Plan S1 Standard, 2 instances.

[The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645242/the-specified-cgi-application-encountered-an-error-and-the-server-terminated-the)

Comment: have you tried all the answer from the last link ?

Comment: @Thomas I can not access to App Service Plan to modify as the last link so right now i'm stuck here, my code run locally okay so I think problem come from ASP.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, after debugging it turned out i had an unhandled exception inside a Parallel.Foreach Loop. The parallel loop did not have any try/catch within it, and as a result having an exception thrown bubbled up to the app domain killing and restarting the web app, with this same error showing: 
"The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process."
You should check all your asynchronous threads for error capturing

Comment: I tried to implement try catch the library I used, but it's still not work, the request run below 120s it's okay but over 120s the error above happen.

Comment: And i don't use any async or await feature, no parallel for each loop as well, I implement loop but it's sequence

Comment: In case the library you are using is facing any unhandled exception within a thread it is creating this might happen as well and the try/catch you added won't help. Check for updates on the library or involve their support