# .NET Core 2.1 Azure Web App: The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt, kestrel

I host my ASP.NET .NET Core 2.1 project in Azure Web App service. I recently upgraded to 2.1 (From 2.0) and I started getting these errors:

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server
>   terminated the process.

The application typically runs just fine for an hour or so and then suddenly it crashes and all responses return this error. I have to restart it to make the error go away. It was working fine with .NET Core 2.0.

I saw similar issues posted on SO that turned out to be related to earlier Kestrel versions. It shouldn't be the case for me. My project references Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 which has the latest Kestrel version.

This is my production environment, please help.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Darey nope, I downgraded back to 2.0. Will wait for a bit until I upgrade again.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645242/the-specified-cgi-application-encountered-an-error-and-the-server-terminated-the

Answer (score -1):

So finally, I saw there were few extensions added to my azure app service and post deleting the extensions under "Custom" my service is running as expected.

Comment: Could you elaborate please.

Comment: @Andrei most likely removing the extensions caused the app to restart which likely cleared the issue. :(