# How to handle the performance issue in Azure app service

Tags: azure, performance, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I have hosted Api in azure app service.

IT was working fine but now after hitting the API it is returning status code as 502 with message

`The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.`

I have restarted the app service and it started working fine but this is happening frequently.

Is there a way to get alerts or have an automatic restart of app service if this is happening frequently or any other suggestions.

This is I found in the Azure performance

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciatable.
Thanks for the help

Comment: You should add application insights to your project to get detailed logs to identify the issue in your code.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645242/the-specified-cgi-application-encountered-an-error-and-the-server-terminated-the

Answer (score 1):

Main reasons for this type of error in app service are:

- requests taking a long time
- application using high memory/CPU
- application crashing due to an exception.

For troubleshooting see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-http-502-http-503

For autorestarting Azure web site see: https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/blog/auto-healing-windows-azure-web-sites/