# Using Java in Azure I get "Specified CGI application encountered an error"

Tags: java, azure

Sometimes deploying this code works other times I have the error "The specified CGI application encountered an error when browsing to the site"
I tried changed the code, chaging azure configurations.
Where am I wrong?

````
<body >
    <div id="feature">
       <div id="content">
             <h2> Java </h2>
            <br/>
        <br/>
            <table width="750" frame="below">
              <tr bgcolor="rgb(13,188,242)">  
                <th align="left" width="300">    Property  </th>  
                <th align="left" width="500">    Value  </th>
              </tr>
              <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
              <%
                    int mb = 1024*1024;
        
                    //Getting the runtime reference from system
                    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    //Print total available memory
                    out.print("<tr><td>Total Memory (Mb)");
                    out.print("</td><td>" + runtime.totalMemory() / mb);
                    out.print("</td></tr>");
                    //Print Maximum available memory
                    out.print("<tr><td>Max Memory (Mb)");
                    out.print("</td><td>" + runtime.maxMemory() / mb);
                    out.print("</td></tr>");
              %>
            </table>
          </font>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>```
````

Comment: This seems to be a common mistake, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645242/the-specified-cgi-application-encountered-an-error-and-the-server-terminated-the